# Quick way to delete multiple columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The data has around 60 columns. I'm looking for a quicker way to delete multiple columns.
The data is also a data source for pivot tables in the workbook.

The below is working but still,  I need it to run quicker.

```
For col = 1 To LC
    If .Cells(1, col) <> "HM/Candidate" And .Cells(1, col) <> "Step" And .Cells(1, col) <> "Channel" And _
        .Cells(1, col) <> "Month Name" And .Cells(1, col) <> "Year" And .Cells(1, col) <> "Date" And _
        .Cells(1, col) <> "FY" And .Cells(1, col) <> "FQ" And .Cells(1, col) <> "Name" And _
        .Cells(1, col) <> "Workflow" And .Cells(1, col) <> "Update" Then
        If .Cells(1, col) = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            Columns(col).EntireColumn.Delete
            LC = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            col = col - 1
        End If
    End If
Next col
End With
```

Comment: If the columns to keep are less than those to delete, then copy the ones you want to keep to a new sheet, then delete the rest.

Comment: You should never change the value of a loop contol variable, so this line should not be used ' LC = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column'.  In the case you have shown you should make the loop 'LC to 1 step -1' then you will not need to adjust the value of LC.

Comment: @SolarMike i guess it will not work peoperly since the data is connected to pivots and slicers

Comment: "you guess"? ok then. We dealt with a lot of data and we managed a massive change in speed by understanding our data.

Comment: Q: Maybe the "fastest/easiest" way is to forget about VBA, and just open Excel; highlight the columns, and hit the "Delete" key?  How often will you be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This should be faster than deleting columns in a loop. This identifies the columns to delete and then deletes them in the end in one go.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LCol As Long
    Dim DelRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 1 To LCol
            Select Case .Cells(1, i).Value
            Case "HM/Candidate", "Step", "Channel", "Month Name", _
                 "Year", "Date", "FY", "FQ", "Name", "Workflow", "Update", ""
            Case Else
                If DelRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set DelRange = .Columns(i)
                Else
                    Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, .Columns(i))
                End If
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
    
    If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that different way. I'd define list of obligatory columns, then i'd delete all columns which are out of bound.

You can use a collection or a dictionary object. But!, if you would like to use a dictionary, you need to add reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (in the Code window: Tools-> References) first. A dictionary object is more flexible, because it constains "Exists" method.

A dictionary object contains a pair: key and value. So, you can define column name and its index (where it should be placed).

For example:

```
Dim d As Dictionary
Dim item As Variant

Set d = New Dictionary
d.Add "ColumnName", "ColumnIndex"

If d.Exists("ColumnName") Then
    item = d("ColumnName")
    Debug.Print item
End If
```

The rest belongs to you.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Columns By Headers

```vb
Sub DeleteColsByHeaders()
    
    Const FIRST_HEADER_CELL As String = "A1"
    
    Dim KeepHeaders(): KeepHeaders = Array( _
        "HM/Candidate", "Step", "Channel", "Month Name", "Year", _
        "Date", "FY", "FQ", "Name", "Workflow", "Update")
    
    Dim hrg As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet ' improve!
        Dim fhCell As Range: Set fhCell = .Range(FIRST_HEADER_CELL)
        Dim lhCell As Range:
        Set lhCell = .Cells(fhCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
        Set hrg = .Range(fhCell, lhCell)
    End With
        
    Dim hArr(): hArr = Application.Match(hrg, KeepHeaders, 0)
    
    Dim hrgDel As Range, c As Long, IsDeleteColumnFound As Boolean
    
    For c = 1 To UBound(hArr)
        If IsError(hArr(c)) Then ' not found in 'KeepHeaders' array; combine
            If IsDeleteColumnFound Then
                Set hrgDel = Union(hrgDel, hrg.Cells(c).EntireColumn)
            Else
                Set hrgDel = hrg.Cells(c).EntireColumn
                IsDeleteColumnFound = True
            End If
        'Else ' found in 'KeepHeaders' array; do nothing
        End If
    Next c
    
    If IsDeleteColumnFound Then hrgDel.Delete
    
End Sub
```